# Select label based on its 'for' value in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, controls, label

I have a asp.net page which contains checkbox controls like below:

```
<input name="REQUEST_DA_TYPE$0" disabled="disabled" id="REQUEST_DA_TYPE_0" type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
<label for="REQUEST_DA_TYPE_0">
Text - Accept
<input name="REQUEST_DA_TYPE$1" disabled="disabled" id="REQUEST_DA_TYPE_1" type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
<label for="REQUEST_DA_TYPE_1">
Text - Refuse
```

Now I need to dynamically change both label's text in C# page.
Help me to solve this.

Comment: Can you modify this page? if yes then that is the solution for your problem.

Comment: No I can't modify the asp page.

Comment: @sanmathi: if you want to do this on the server side i.e., on C# page then you could easily use the server control since your code above would make sense only when you need do 'dynamically change both label's text' in the front end thro' js

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use server controls instead of native html elements directly? That's one of the main features of ASP.NET, isn't it? So, instead of doing this...

```
<input name="REQUEST_DA_TYPE$0" disabled="disabled" id="REQUEST_DA_TYPE_0" type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
<label for="REQUEST_DA_TYPE_0">

<input name="REQUEST_DA_TYPE$1" disabled="disabled" id="REQUEST_DA_TYPE_1" type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
<label for="REQUEST_DA_TYPE_1">
```

Why don't you do this...?

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="REQUEST_DA_TYPE_0" runat="server" Checked="True" Enabled="false" Text="Text - Accept"/>
<asp:CheckBox ID="REQUEST_DA_TYPE_1" runat="server" Checked="True" Enabled="false" Text="Text - Refuse"/>
```

Then, from code behind you can change whatever you want. For example, the text...

```
REQUEST_DA_TYPE_0.Text = "I've been changed";
```

enable it...

```
REQUEST_DA_TYPE_0.Enabled = false;
```

the font color...

```
REQUEST_DA_TYPE_0.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
```

etc, etc.

Comment: I cant modify the controls.I have to use this control only.

Comment: @sanmathi you are not using any controls at all, so, in simple words...what you are trying to do it's NOT possible without changing your html